# Is it right to use FixedUpdate in my case?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I hope my question isn't too dumb, I am not very familiar with FixedUpdate.
I know FixedUpdate is usually used with physics, but in my game, I have the following problem : when it runs at a low fps rate, the enemies skip checkpoints (because they move too much in a frame).
The movements method :

```
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        TestIfCloseToOtherZombie();
        //chopper la direction dans laquelle aller
        Vector3 dir = target.position - transform.position;
        //déplacer l'enemy
        transform.Translate(dir.normalized * enemy.speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, Space.World);
        Vector3 rotDir = new Vector3(dir.x, 0, dir.z);
        if(rotDir != Vector3.zero)
        {
            Quaternion lookRotation =  Quaternion.LookRotation(rotDir);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, turnSpeed*Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }

        //marge d'erreur pour éviter qu'il bug dans le waypoint (+ de speed = + de  marge sinon bug)
        if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) <= enemy.wayPointPrecision){
            GetNextWaypoint();
        }

        if(!isToClose)
        {
            enemy.speed = enemy.baseSpeed;
        }
        
        GetCurrentPosition();
    }
```

Target is the checkpoint the enemy is going to.
Previously, I used a wayPointPrecision value, to solve the problem. But when the fps are way to low, it's not enough.

I just want to know if FixedUpdate could be used to make sure the movements are calculated independently from framerate, even if it does not use physics.

Answer (score 1):

FixedUpdate in your situation will not solve the issue, however you could use [MoveTowards()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) instead that will not overshoot the target, in your example it could be as simple as:

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, Time.deltaTime * 2);
```

Comment: Actually, it seems to work with FixedUpdate. However I tried your solution and it works too for the movement, but the function TestIfCloseToOtherZombie (it calculates the distance between enemies) isn't called enough. That function also modifies the speed of the enemy, which is used here (if that could help).

Comment: Actually, I am trying to invokeRepeating those instead of using update, maybe it will work.

Comment: It's tough to say without seeing what the function TestIfCloseToOtherZombie() does exactly and what is the goal of it, but and as long as it is called in the same loop it should be called the same number of times. It is however called before the updated position is applied (I don't know if it is intended to do so or not) but you could be "missing calls" because of that or because I can see that the TestIfCloseToOtherZombie doesn't return anything to your movement function, the move function gets executed no matter what the outcome of TestIfCloseToOtherZombie is.

Comment: It raycast forward and if there is an other zombies too close, it slows down the speed. I managed to make it all work using invokeRepeating.

Answer (score 0):

After trying some different ways, everything works fine using InvokeRepeating() instead of update or fixedupdate.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of FixedUpdate is not "Physics" per se - The purpose of FixedUpdate *determinism.* If you're moving an object in a way that is *mechanically significant* (That is, the movement of that object has an impact on how the game plays, rather than simply how the game looks or feels), then that behavior probably belongs in FixedUpdate. This always applies to physics, but it also applies to basically anything that might involve a collision check of any kind.